# This method is meant to print different values for every hour spent in excess of two hours in a car park but instead it prints the largest sum

Tags: c#

The purpose of this method is to calculate and display parking charges for 
each customer who parked a car in this garage , but instead it just prints 
the maximum value i.e 10 dollars for any customer that spends over 3 hours.

```
double CalculateCharges(double time) //method header
{
    if (time >= 0 && time <= 3)
        //returns 2 if the individual spends 3 or less hours
        //in the car park
        return 2.0;                             
    else if (time > 3 && time <= 24) // if time is greater than 3 hrs  then do this
    {
        double basic = 2.0; // basic charge to a customer  
        for (time = 4; time <= 19; time++)
        {
            // basic charge + 0.5 for every extra hour over 3 hrs
            basic += 0.5;  
        }
        return basic;
    }
    else 
        //if the person spends more than 19 hrs lets the
        // person pay a maximum of 10 dollars
        return 10; 

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use a Timespan instead of a double parameter?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I haven't gotten to that level but I'll do some research ASAP

Comment: perhaps a Switch (case) statement might be worth looking into as well

Comment: for 24 cases? @ITAlex

Comment: @ITAlex I don't think a switch statement would help much in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop will always calculate the same value because you are always counting `time` from 4 to 19. Better change it to something like this, adding a new control variable `i`:

```
double basic = 2.0;
for (int i = 4; i <= Math.Ceiling(time); i++)
{
    basic += 0.5;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also calculate the price directly, avoiding a loop:

```
var price = 2.0 + (Math.Ceiling(time) - 3) * 0.5;
```

Comment: This won't work properly if `time` has a decimal part, e.g. `4.50`. Consider using [Math.Ceiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified decimal number

Comment: you need to do it in the loop as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know your method uses a double as a parameter, but allow me to provide an alternative using a Timespan, which is IMO more adequate in this situation:

```
public static double CalculateCharges(TimeSpan time) 
{
    if (time < TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parking time cannot be less than 0", nameof(time));
    }

    const double initialPrice = 2.0;
    const double maxPrice = 10.0;

    if (time <= TimeSpan.FromHours(3))
    {
        return initialPrice;
    }

    if (time >= TimeSpan.FromHours(19))
    {
        return maxPrice;
    }

    // ignore the first 3 hours
    int hours = time.Hours - 3;

    // if time is 1 hour and 5 minutes we should charge 2 hours
    // No need to check for seconds, I suppose :)
    if (time.Minutes > 0)
    {
        hours++;
    }

    double finalPrice = initialPrice + (hours * 0.5);

    return finalPrice;
}
```

Testing the code:

```
TimeSpan twentyMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); 
TimeSpan twoHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(2); 
TimeSpan threeHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(3); 
TimeSpan threeHoursAndAHalf = new TimeSpan(3, 30, 0); 
TimeSpan fiveHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(5); 
TimeSpan tenHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(10); 
TimeSpan nineteenHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(19); 
TimeSpan twentyHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(20); 

Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(twentyMinutes)}) = {CalculateCharges(twentyMinutes):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(twoHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(twoHours):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(threeHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(threeHours):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(threeHoursAndAHalf)}) = {CalculateCharges(threeHoursAndAHalf):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(fiveHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(fiveHours):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(tenHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(tenHours):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(nineteenHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(nineteenHours):C}");
Console.WriteLine($"CalculateCharges({nameof(twentyHours)}) = {CalculateCharges(twentyHours):C}");
```

Output:

[image: Console output]